# Only apply certain CSS styles when class doesn't also exist on element

Tags: html, css, less

Say I have two CSS classes:

```
.class1 {
   color: red;
}

.class2 {
  /* Has Stuff */
}
```

I only want to apply whatever styles `class1` has IF `class2` is not also on the element. So for example:

```
<div class="class1">Some div</div>
```

Should be in red.

However, if I do:

```
<div class="class1 class2">Some div</div>
```

Should NOT be red, even if `class2` doesn't have anything related defined in it.

How can I do this?

Comment: using `not()` selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.class1:not(.class2) {
   color: red;
}
```

This should work for you